# Stop auto-expanding functions in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I'd like to make it so that functions and for loops do not auto-expand when I run them.

I have some very long functions, so it can be easy to lose my place since they expand.

It's totally possible that this is not something that can be done and it's baked into R.

Right now, when I run a function, it expands. I'd like to run it and have it not expand.

This takes place in the latest version of R on Mac in RMarkdown

This is an example. Put this code into an r mark down block

```
  for(i in 1:3){


    
    
  }
```

And then press the caret next to the line number

And then run the function. I'd like for it to stay closed

Comment: what do you by expands?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Hi @tadon11Aaa I don't know how to stop RStudio from doing that. The official terms for this behaviour is Code Folding, Expand, and Collapse.  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections